# VB.Net Order values in a List of Dictionaries

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, dictionary

I'm working with a List of Dictionaries. I want to order each Dictionary inside the list by its values. I'm trying these two options:

1)

```
Dim myList As List(Of Dictionary(Of Integer, Single))          
myList.ForEach(Function(x) x.OrderBy(Function(a) a.Value).ToDictionary(Function(y) y.Key, Function(y) y.Value))
```

2)

```
Dim myList As List(Of Dictionary(Of Integer, Single))          
For Each element In myList
    element = element.OrderBy(Function(a) a.Value).ToDictionary(Function(y) y.Key, Function(y) y.Value)
Next
```

However, none of these works. Can somebody help me?

Comment: dictionaries aren't sorted.

Comment: have you considered using `SortedDictionary`?

Comment: I need to order the dictionaries by it values and `Sorted Dictionary` it does but by it keys

Comment: perhaps you need a different data structure then.

Comment: I tried with `List(Of List(Of single))` and I get the same result. When I use the second option the object `element` is ordered but isn´t saved in the list. I think I have to use a temporary structure and save `element` in it